# How to add exponents so that they are in the form $a^{b^{a}}$

Tags: exponentiation, exponential-sum

I have these exponents which I wish to add together

$$10^{10^{200}} + 10^{10^{100}}$$

How do I add them such that the resulting exponent is in the form $a^{b^{a}}$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers?

Comment: Try first $10^{10^2}+10^{10^1}$ yourself, and then consider the original problem afterwards.

Comment: @TomFinet Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
Note that
$${10}^{10^{200}} 
={10}^{10^{100\times 2}} 
={10}^{(10^{100})^2} 
={10}^{(10^{100})(10^{100})} 
=({10}^{10^{100}}) {}^{(10^{100})}.
$$
So, knowing that $x^m+x=x(x^{m-1} +1)$, we get
$${10}^{10^{200}} +{10}^{10^{100}} 
=({10}^{10^{100}}) {}^{(10^{100})} +{10}^{10^{100}} 
=({10}^{10^{100}}) \Big(
{10}^{10^{100} -1} +1\Big).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\large{10^{10^{200}}+10^{10^{100}}=10^{\overbrace{1000...000}^{\text{200 zeros}}}}+10^{\overbrace{1000...000}^{\text{100 zeros}}}\approx \large{10^{10^{200}}}$$